# Does HBase support ACID just as Hive does?

Tags: hive, transactions, hbase, acid

as https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions says, Hive supports some limited ACID transactions. SO, if I just need row-level transactions, is Hive enough? Is HBase's advantages become less and less?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do ACID transactions in HBase with [Apache Phoenix](https://phoenix.apache.org/), a layer for HBase which provides an SQL interface for handling data.

To use transactions, after installing Phoenix you set the property `phoenix.transactions.enabled` to `true` in your hbase-site.xml , then use the `TRANSACTIONAL` option when you create your table.  For example:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, val VARCHAR) TRANSACTIONAL=true;
```

Following that you simply interact with your table normally, with SQL through JDBC or another interface.  (Note you can also alter an existing non-transactional table to be transactional.)

For more, you can read about Phoenix and its transaction support at the project's website:

https://phoenix.apache.org/transactions.html